# Eliminate branching when find median in a binary {0, 255} image

Tags: c++, c, optimization, image-processing

I have a *binary* image, the *binary* value is either 0 or 255. the type of the image data is **unsigned char**. Here I need to do a median filtering on this image.

I think using a *histogram* to find the median should be fast. Using some codes to explain:

```
unsigned int hist[2] = {0, 0};

for (int i = 0; i < kernel_h; ++i) {
     for (int j = 0; j < kernel_w; ++j) {
          if (image(i,j) == 0) {
              hist[0]++;
          }
          else {
              hist[1]++;
          }
     }
}
```

Then, we could get the median value very fast. But due to this case, the codes still could be improved：

```
int counter = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < kernel_h; ++i) {
     for (int j = 0; j < kernel_w; ++j) {
          if (image(i,j) == 0) {
              counter++
          }
          else {
              counter--;
          }
     }
}
```

But I wonder is there some other way to eliminate the if-else branch, like using bit operations to map {0, 255} to something so that we could just update a flag without branching.

Anybody any suggestion ?

Comment: Is vectorization an option for you? And what platform are you on? 3x3 and 5x5 median filters on binary images are trivially vectorizable on both x86 and ARM processors, using SSE, NEON or DSP extensions. On byte-sized data, you should be able to process 16 pixels at once with SSE.

Answer (score 11):

All bits of 255 are 1 so you can simplify that "if" to:

```
hist[image(i,j) & 1]++;
```

If you want to use the counter you can do:

```
counter += (image(i,j) & 2)-1;
```

Comment: The `counter` example can be simplified even further. You're doing `kernel_h * kernel_w` subtractions of -1 each, which are easily hoisted out of the loop to a single `counter -= kernel_w * kernel_h`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: The `&2` gives you +2 or 0. The original code used counter++ and counter--, so +1 and -1. The difference per pixel is a constant -1.

Comment: Ah. It would be clearer if you explained you are eliminating just part of the counter increment, not the whole expression. Additionally, if `kernel_h` and `kernel_w` are not large (so overflow will not be an issue), there is no need for `& 2`. Just use `counter += image(i, j);` and scale `counter` appropriately after the loop ends.

Answer (score 5):

This computation can be made MUCH faster and more specifically `O(n)` in the number of pixels and independent on the kernel size.

The idea is to do first a "scan conversion" computing a [summed area table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summed_area_table) in which the value of each (x, y) pixel is replaced by the sum of all pixels from (0, 0) to (x, y).

Given this you can know in fixed time how many pixels are set in any rect using

```
st(x0, y0) + st(x1, y1) - st(x0, y1) - st(x1, y0)
```

and given that each pixel was 0 or 1 the sum gives you the count of ones.

The total computation time is `O(n)` to build the sum table and `O(n)` to do the median filtering, no matter how big is the area where to do the counting.

In the case of median filtering you could precompute the result depending on the sum and the formula in the inner loop could be:

```
result[x] = res[p0[x] + p1[x+box] - p0[x+box] - p1[x]];
```

Moreover the sum table doesn't need to be computed completely (thus requiring one integer per pixel) but it could be computed "lazily" while doing the result and you need only as many lines of the table as the height of the kernel still keeping computing time `O(image_width*image_height)` but requiring only `kernel_height*image_width` memory.

Comment: Yes, you're right, using a integral image (or sum-table) could be a better way if the image or the kernel is relatively bigger. But in order to implement this algorithm, we need another memory buffer chunk, and for every kernel window, we have to do a division to get the number of *1*. Here my kernel size is small, e.g. 3x3 or 5x5, and image size is small too. So I choose the straight forward way to do my job.

Comment: @user1786323: see edit. Division can be trivially avoided by using a lookup table with `kernel_area` elements.